# Raspberry PI 4 autostart python program after boot using LXDE

Tags: pi-4, linux, lxde, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I have a python script which is using tkinter GUI library. I have initially tried to run the script after boot using systemd method but I got error regarding the tkinter. I have looked it up online and it seems that everyone is having the same issue with systemd and suggests using LXDE.

I have modified my LXDE autostart file and added the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
```

```
@/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/PTL/my_program.py
```

But after reboot the program does not start.
If I run the same command on the terminal, the program starts without any problems.

My program is using GPIO library, tkinter library and is making HTTP requests. I have ensured that my Raspberry PI is waiting for network before boot. I am not sure what else to try. Is there any way to see LXDE logs and see why it fails?

Comment: I think you've got the wrong folder: /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

Comment: @CoderMike: Maybe make this an answer to keep this question out of the "Un-answered questions that are perpetually re-cycled" stack?

Comment: No matter what I did I could not get it to work using LXDE. I have found another very simple method. I have created .desktop file for my python application and then created a launch after boot from that .desktop file. The detailed description can be found here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=294014 under Traditional System Method

Comment: So you didn’t try using the LXDE-pi folder?

Comment: I havent since I got it to work using .desktop method I left it at that.